# How can I extract title and list-item contents from HTML into a comma-separated list?

Tags: html, regex, sed

My regex-fu is sadly lacking and though I am reading "Mastering Regex" and reading some online tutorials I am getting nowhere so hope perhaps if someone can give me a practical example for my situation it will help me to get started.

Input files look roughly like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My Title</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <p>Various random text...</p>
 <ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li><a href="example.com">Two</a></li>
  <li>Three</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Various random text...</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

My eventual goal is to output:

```
My Title,One,<a href="example.com">Two</a>,Three
```

e.g. A comma separated values with title, and the content of the li tags

First step though is to try to remove everything before and including title, so as I decided to use sed (I have GNU sed version 4.2 running on windows) I try as follows:

Figuring I need to match "everything" including newlines up to the title tag and replace with nothing that means:

match every character with a dot, and also newlines /n so make that a class and make it repeat with * which means [.\n]* followed by the title tag
replace with nothing

so

```
type file.html | sed "s/[.\n]*<title>//"
```

But this doesn't work, it just removes the string  title  but not the things before it.

Where am I going wrong?  I want to understand.

Any advice appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to used `sed`?

Comment: No, sed just seemed reasonable to deal with a bunch of text files.  It's quite ok to use another tool (if I have it!)

Comment: I generally would always recommend using a HTML parser, unless this is a quick-and-dirty once-off and you can make some guarantees about the HTML.

Comment: It is a quick and dirty and I can guarantee the HTML.  Normally I would do a parser too, it would take me only a few minutes as I do this a lot.  But I believe (presume, think, guess) that it would be even faster with regex, hence my attempt to learn how to do it that way.

Comment: "Faster" how?  You mean in execution time?  How often do you think you're going to run this that execution time is important?

Comment: I meant faster to code.  As I often have to do one-off throwaway text processing like this I'm looking to learn more efficient ways, in terms of less time/effort for myself.

Comment: `sed` processes a single line at a time; a single pattern cannot contain a newline. You can accumulate text from multiple lines but the script will generally require various complications to work correctly, to the point where Perl or Awk may be more natural tools for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed (and tr, and sed...):

```
sed -n -e '/<title>\|<li>/{s/^[ ]*<[^>]*>//;s/<[^>]*>[ ]*$//p}' input | \
    tr '\n' , | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

Using a single sed expression:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;        # loop, read-in all file, remove newlines 
     s/.*<title>//;            # remove everything up to, including <title>
     s/title>.*<ul>/title>/;   # remove everything between </title> and <ul>
     s!</ul>.*!!;              # remove everything after </ul>, inclusive
     s!</li>\|</title>!,!g;    # substitute closing tags with commas
     s/<li>//g;                # remove <li> tags
     s/,[ ]*$//                # delete the trailing comma
     ' input
```

Comment: Thank you, that works and more importantly the clear explanation assists with my overall goal of understanding/learning how to use this technique.

Answer (score 0):

#### A Ruby Solution

You can do what you want in a variety of ways, some more elegant than others. Here's a quick-and-dirty way to get your expected results with a single Ruby one-liner.

```
ruby -ne 'BEGIN { output = "" }
          output << $1 + ?, if %r{<(?:title|li)>(.*)</\1?}
          END { puts output.sub(/,$/, "") }' /tmp/foo.html
```

This script will print the result in the format described in the original question. For example, with the sample text provided it prints:

```
My Title,One,<a href="example.com">Two</a>,Three
```